# Wireshark capture a website packets

Tags: wireshark

In my browser I connect to **www.superuser.com** In wireshark filter I want to access to those packet which I receive from this web site. what is that filter?

Note : I do not want to use ip address.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) filter

```
host www.stackexchange.com
```

should work. If not, there's a [thread](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/1090/filter-apparently-doesnt-support-host-name-format-for-address) in Wshark forum that suggests format

```
ip.dst_host www.superuser.com
```

which worked for asker there.

Comment: thank you but I try both of them but not work

Comment: @alex Wireshark needs to resolve the name *www.superuser.com* to an IP because the string `www.superuser.com` is nowhere in your captured packets. So, it is *not* possible to filter for *www.superuser.com* without resolving the name to an IP first (e.g via hosts file)

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't have wshark to test with just then... now I did. The filter needs to be in usual Wshark format ip.dst_host == stackexchange.com. There shouldn't be a need to resolve with hosts file, as there's standard DNS resolution before the actual HTTP packet goes. The DNS name is in the payload of the HTTP packet. According to the wiki ip.dst_host is a valid filter, and Wshark accepts it. However I get no results using it either as capture or display filter, so it might be the filter is broken. Note that the display filter reference mentions neither ip.dst nor ip.dst_host.

Comment: Well, I too tested it before commenting and it didn't show something either. So I assumed it has to do something with name resolving, like your thread also said

Comment: I just tested by editing the host file. No difference. So either this filter works differently than other Wshark filters, or it is indeed broken.

Comment: I dropped a question to the Wireshark Q/A forum. Let's see...